# ExtJS--remove row from a treegrid

Tags: extjs

I have a treegrid exactly like the ExtJS Kitchen Sink TreeGrid Example:

[http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/example/build/KitchenSink/ext-theme-neptune/#tree-grid]

how can I remove a row? I checked the docs and it seems treestore didnt inherit the store remove method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything in a TreeStore is a descendant of the root node so you can just retrieve a node from the store and then call the destroy method.

So:

treeStore.getNodeById('nodeuniqueid').destroy();